# detect EOL in C using fgets

Tags: c, file-io

I'm attempting to read a single line from a file using the following...

```
 while(fgets(c,BUF,f) != EOL){
   puts(c);
 }
```

Where EOL = `#define EOL '\n'` however, I get the warning... `comparison between pointer and integer`

What is the correct way to achieve what I'm trying?

Answer (score 5):

fgets reads a string, and the result type is `char*`

I'd think you are thinking of `fgetc` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try fgetc instead? Then you can compare the ASCII code of '/n' like this

```
while (fgetc (file) != '\n'){
  puts(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference the returned `char*` and compare that to your `EOL` ... not compare the actual pointer address itself to the end-of-line character.

Change your code to this:

```
char* return_val = NULL;
while((return_val = fgets(c,BUF,f)) != NULL && *return_val != EOF)
{
   puts(c);
}

if (retun_val == NULL)
{
    //handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to examine the contents of `c` after the call to `fgets` to determine if a newline was included in the returned string:

```
for (;;) {
 if (fgets(c, BUF, f) == NULL) { /* handle error */ }
 if (strchr(c, EOL) != NULL) {
  puts(c);
 } else {break; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads characters from the stream and writes them in the buffer until either the buffer is almost full or it finds a `'\n'` (it returns NULL if the operation fails).

So you can know how many characeters were read (including the `'\n'`) with `strlen` ...

```
ret = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
if (ret == NULL) /* deal with error */;
chars = strlen(buffer);
```

Now, one of 2 things may have hapenned: either a `'\n'` was read before the buffer got full or the buffer gor full before a `'\n'` was read. You can know which was it by examining the last character in the buffer

```
if (buffer[chars - 1] == '\n') /* full line read */;
else /* incomplete line */;
```

Note that `chars` is always (*) 1 or more, so the expression `buffer[chars - 1]` is ok.

*(*) it could be 0 only with binary data for input, but that denies the use of `strlen` and other string functions.*